# ALTER TABLE table ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (state = '34' , city = '123') is not adding the partition in temp/local folder

Tags: apache-spark-sql, partitioning, hive-metastore, hive-table

I am working on hive table partitioning and using spark client to trigger the request.
I have created the table and inserted data with partition.When I execute select statement I can see the data, but when I add Partition

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE temp_table6 ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (state = '34' , city = '123')")
```

second time onwards I am not able to get the data.
Since spark client looking for partitioned folder in temp location `temp/temp_table6`, spark is throwing an exception like below

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o93.showString.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/tmp/temp_table6/state=34/city=123
```

From second time onwards partitioned data not getting created under temp folder.